# How to release a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK set through MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player, wakelock

I'm setting a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` for my `MediaPlayer` instance using:

```
mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

How can I release it? Is it done in `MediaPlayer.release()` (I can't see anything about it in the doc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is released on `MediaPlayer.release()`, `MediaPlayer.stop()`, and `MediaPlayer.reset()`. It's also released `onCompletion` and `onError`.

Looking through the source for `MediaPlayer` here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer

It looks like `MediaPlayer.stayAwake()` is responsible and this will release the wakelock.

```
private void stayAwake(boolean awake) {
    if (mWakeLock != null) {
        if (awake && !mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        } else if (!awake && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
    mStayAwake = awake;
    updateSurfaceScreenOn();
}
```

This is a private method but it is called in various states, for example in `release()` `stayAwake(false)` is called.

Just search through for `mWakeLock` and `stayAwake(false)` and you'll see. I've also checked as far back as 1.5 and it's the same.